# Displaying data from a normalised m-m relationship

Tags: crud, laravel-backpack, laravel-9

I have have 2 tables, ServiceProvider , Entity. There is a m-m relationship between them so I created a link table spEntity which contains the foreign keys from both the other tables.

I have backpack working fine on the 3 tables separately, I use the relationship type on the spEntity CRUD to show the names from the other 2 tables and this all works fine.

However, what I would like to do is when the ServiceProvider record is being created

- show a list of all the entities
- allow the user to select one and then when the save button is pressed
- create the spEntity record.

I have tried

```
protected function setupCreateOperation()
{
    CRUD::setValidation(ServiceProviderRequest::class);

    CRUD::field('ServiceProviderName');
    CRUD::field('ServiceProviderEmailAddress');
    CRUD::field('ServiceProviderDescription');
    CRUD::addfield(['name'=>'Entity',
                    'type'=>'relationship',
                    'attribute' => 'EntityName',
                    'pivot'=>true,
                    'relation_type'=>'belongstomany'
        ]);
}
```

but I get the error :
BadMethodCallException  PHP 8.1.7   9.19.0
Method Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanel::relationAllowsMultiple does not exist.

[Table relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emxWK.png)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating laravel-backpack/CRUD because seems to be an old bug.

Comment: I believe I am using the latest version:

`code` php artisan backpack:version

### PHP VERSION:

PHP 8.1.7 (cli) (built: Jun 25 2022 08:12:59) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

### LARAVEL VERSION:
v9.19.0@bbce25bd823133f6a5a724f2d62680b711f1d0df

### BACKPACK VERSION:
5.1.4@4539c787a2e052d2e2e2c00188c38432dc2a7ea9

Comment: Apologies for the formatting

Comment: [Gitter discussion about something similar... ](https://gitter.im/BackpackForLaravel/Lobby?at=5eb3edb39f0c955d7dacfabe) probably you should update the backpack/CRUD... would you check get the version from composer.json pls?

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution.

The problem was in my model definition. I need to add in the m-m relationship there.

Model

```
    public function entities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Entity::class,'SPEntity','Entity_idEntity','ServiceProvider_idServiceProvider')
                ->withPivot('idSPEntity')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

then in the Crud controller

```
        CRUD::addfield(['name'=>'entities',
                    'type'=>'select2_multiple',
                    'attribute' => 'EntityName',
                    'pivot'=>true,
                    'relation_type'=>'belongstomany'
        ]);
```

this now displays the field correctly and I can add further entities to the Service Provider.

However the information is not saved.